# When I import variables from another file, console says 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

In file1, I have this code:

```
class goal:
    x = 0
    y = 0
goal1 = goal()
class environment:
    goals = [goal1]
level1 = environment()
level_list = [level1]
```

In file2, I have this:

```
import file1
level = 1
goal = file1.level_list[level].goals
```

The last line in file2 is giving me the error.

I tried looking it up online, and importing just the list, but nothing worked, and I still got the same error.

Comment: Like most programming languages, Python indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with importing? If you assign the variable in `file2`, does it work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index in python starts from 0, being the first element index 0, the second index 1 and so on. The "level_list" list has just one element so you can just access the index 0 from the list and you are trying to use the index 1 wich does not exist.

Just change the variable "level" in file 2 for 0.

```
import file1
level = 0
goal = file1.level_list[0].goals
```